# Array to string conversion [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php, line 612] cakephp session

Tags: session, cakephp

I suddenly started getting this strange error that I cant figure out

```
Notice (8): Array to string conversion [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php, line 612]
```

I checked `CakeSession.php` file and on that line it is just the start session function `session_start();`. Debug level is 2, nothing in cake error logs, im on shared hosting and cant check the apache log.

it shows the error after this line in `AppController`

```
if ($this->Auth->user('id')) {
```

I mean if I put debug and die before that there is no error. But this used to work just fine all the time.

cake v 2.4.2

Thanks